# How do I browse for available gsettings options?

Tags: gnome3, gsettings, dconf

There are certain gsettings keys that can have multiple values (e.g. a key like **verbosity** could be assigned to one `error`, `info`, or `debug`). I want to be able to list them, but my `dconf-editor` (**0.7.3**) can't view them. Is there an existing alternative?

Comment: More information would be helpful. For instance, when you say dconf-editor can't view them, are you seeing errors? Do you think this is a bug with dconf-editor or is it just not used to view gsetting keys? Can it view normal keys, just not keys with multiple values? All of these are questions that would shed some light on your current question. Will using something like gconf overcome this problem? More detail will be infinitely useful. What are you trying to do, what exactly is failing etc.

Comment: @rfelsburg Good points. I have updated my post to clarify.

Comment: BTW, gconf-editor also doesn't have this option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The newer version of **`dconf-editor`** now lists the options.

[image]

In this example, if you click on `debug`, you'll see a list of other available values. This screenshot is of version **0.10** of the tool.

A screenshoot from v0.19.3, shows options:

[image]

Comment: The text mentions there's other options. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, I prefer my image. The theme is nicer and the image smaller (less noise, less wasted space). I am nit-picking of course.

Comment: Good news: `dconf-editor` still exists and works in Ubuntu 22.04 as well. Install it with `sudo apt install dconf-editor`.

Answer (score 17):

You could also do that in CLI with `gsettings`:

```sh
gsettings range SCHEMA [:PATH]  KEY
```

where

```sh
range
           Queries the range of valid values for KEY.
```

In your case:

```sh
$ gsettings range org.freedesktop.Tracker.Store verbosity
enum
'errors'
'minimal'
'detailed'
'debug'
```

Answer (score 1):

Complement to the main answer on Dconf-Editor:

In version 3.18.2 - the drop down list of options contains less than what is listed in the more detailed description in the lower part of the window.

Example for `org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar`:

[image]

*Menu, lower, shade* and *none* options are not available in the drop-down list and cannot be selected with Dconf Editor - but they are listed in the lower part of the window inside the more detailed description.

To select those options, one could use the terminal - with something like

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-right-click-titlebar 'minimize'
```

---

The newer version 3.28.0 fixes this - along with a new design.

[image]

Comment: @don_crissti - I was testing with 3.18.2 in an ubuntu16.04-based system. In ubuntu 18.04 I see the newer 3.28.0 version which is not affected.

Answer (score -2):

you can get it through `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.nautilus.gschema.xml` or you have to use `gconf-editor`.

Comment: see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11164/how-do-i-browse-for-available-gsettings-options/66631#comment14832_11164 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29518/